# Wordpress: how to add custom post category to the permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I'm using [Cherry Framework](http://cherryframework.com). And my theme includes a custom post type: **Portfolios** and I've created two categories under this post type: **Readers Stories(slug: readers-stories)** and **Readers Tips(slug: readers-tips)**.

When I create a post under Portfolios and assign them to one of the category(ex: Readers Stories) the permalink for that post will look like this:

`mysite.com/portfolios/example_post`

But I want the URL to be:

`mysite.com/portfolios/readers-stories/example_post`

How can I achieve this?

I tried to use the [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) plugin. But I did not get the desired result.

Here is `register_post_type` function for the **Portfolios** post type:

```
register_post_type( 'portfolio',
            array( 
            'label' => theme_locals("portfolio"),
            'singular_label' => theme_locals("portfolio"),
            '_builtin' => false,
            'public' => true, 
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'page',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/images/icon_portfolio.png',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'portfolio',
                'with_front' => FALSE,
            ),
            'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'editor',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'excerpt',
                    'custom-fields',
                    'comments')
                ) 
            );
register_taxonomy('portfolio_category', 'portfolio', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => theme_locals("categories"), 'singular_name' => theme_locals("category"), "rewrite" => true, "query_var" => true));
register_taxonomy('portfolio_tag', 'portfolio', array('hierarchical' => false, 'label' => theme_locals("tags"), 'singular_name' => theme_locals("tag"), 'rewrite' => true, 'query_var' => true));
```

Comment: Have you tried giving your taxonomies, `rewrite => array('slug' => 'readers-stories')`  You should be using `register_taxonomy` and registering the taxonomies with a rewrite that I showed above.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I'll look into `register_taxonomy` and see how I can use it.

Comment: Also, you do NOT have the taxonomies defined within the post_type, in `register_post_type('portfolio', ...`, you will need `'taxonomies' => array('portfolio_category', 'portfolio_tag'),` within the `args` array.  Than you need to give your rewrite within the `register_taxonomy` function as I described above.  Than you should refresh/flush your permalinks, by going to wordpress admin -> General -> Permalinks and clicking on the Save button at the bottom of that page to reset permalinks.

Comment: ok. cool. Can I use a plugin to create the taxonomies? Because the above function is included in the theme files. I don't want to modify the theme files as they get overwritten when theme is updated.

Comment: That's a bit tricky, if the post type was registered within a hook, like `init` or something, than you can just `remove_action` on it, but it will remove all functionality within that action that the theme adds.  There is no way to unregister a post type and reregister it that I know of in wordpress.  Best way is to just do the editing to the functions.php file itself, than if theme gets updated, keep your edits and make changes as needed.

Comment: Thanks Solomon, I got it working. I  added the `'taxonomies' => array('portfolio_category', 'portfolio_tag'),` to `register_post_type` function. And with plugin - **Custom Post Type Permalinks**, I defined the permalink structure to include `portfolio_category`. It's working.

Comment: Awesome, Congrats!